# using Mupdf library for pdfrenderer not working

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, mupdf, pdfrenderer

I have been working on MuPdf library for long and finally I am able to install it on my device, after creating libmupdf.so file and working on Cygwin and android-ndk.
But still i am facing an issue...application installed on device, I am getting a list of various pdf's I already hv on my device, i click on anyone, but instead of rendering and showing on the viewer, it tries to render, and then again i get the list of pdf's, without getting my pdf to view.

Ny ideas, whats going wrong....

```
04-23 14:44:36.741: D/dalvikvm(11539): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-23 14:44:47.411: I/System.out(11539): Trying to open /mnt/sdcard/Download/BecomeAnXcoder.pdf
04-23 14:44:47.411: D/dalvikvm(11539): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.artifex.mupdf/lib/libmupdf.so 0x4051ebc8
04-23 14:44:47.411: D/dalvikvm(11539): Added shared lib /data/data/com.artifex.mupdf/lib/libmupdf.so 0x4051ebc8
04-23 14:44:47.411: D/dalvikvm(11539): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.artifex.mupdf/lib/libmupdf.so 0x4051ebc8, skipping init
04-23 14:44:47.421: E/libmupdf(11539): Opening document...
04-23 14:44:47.421: E/libmupdf(11539): Done!
04-23 14:44:47.451: I/[POST_RESELECT](11539): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40103c78,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:44:47.451: I/[POST_RESELECT](11539): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4013faa8,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:44:47.451: I/[POST_RESELECT](11539): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40103c78,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:44:47.451: I/[POST_RESELECT](11539): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4013faa8,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:44:47.621: E/libmupdf(11539): Goto page 0...
04-23 14:44:47.741: E/libmupdf(11539): PageWidth=1191
04-23 14:44:47.741: E/libmupdf(11539): PageHeight=1684
04-23 14:44:47.741: D/dalvikvm(11539): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 133K, 48% free 2864K/5447K, external 0K/0K, paused 68ms
04-23 14:44:47.761: E/libmupdf(11539): Goto page 1...
04-23 14:44:47.871: E/libmupdf(11539): PageWidth=1191
04-23 14:44:47.871: E/libmupdf(11539): PageHeight=1684
04-23 14:44:47.871: D/dalvikvm(11539): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 17K, 48% free 2849K/5447K, external 62K/574K, paused 96ms
04-23 14:44:47.901: E/libmupdf(11539): Goto page 0...
04-23 14:44:48.021: E/libmupdf(11539): PageWidth=1191
04-23 14:44:48.021: E/libmupdf(11539): PageHeight=1684
04-23 14:44:48.021: I/libmupdf(11539): In native method
04-23 14:44:48.021: D/dalvikvm(11539): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 9K, 48% free 2852K/5447K, external 627K/1139K, paused 57ms
04-23 14:44:48.021: I/libmupdf(11539): Checking format
04-23 14:44:48.021: I/libmupdf(11539): locking pixels
04-23 14:44:48.021: E/libmupdf(11539): Rendering page=320x452 patch=[0,0,320,452]
04-23 14:44:50.951: W/KeyCharacterMap(11604): Can't open keycharmap file
04-23 14:44:50.951: W/KeyCharacterMap(11604): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'
04-23 14:44:50.951: I/KeyCharacterMap(11604): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-23 14:45:28.941: D/dalvikvm(11675): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 49% free 2765K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 54ms
04-23 14:45:37.901: I/System.out(11675): Trying to open /mnt/sdcard/Download/1430236051iOS5SDK.pdf
04-23 14:45:37.901: D/dalvikvm(11675): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.artifex.mupdf/lib/libmupdf.so 0x4051f240
04-23 14:45:37.911: D/dalvikvm(11675): Added shared lib /data/data/com.artifex.mupdf/lib/libmupdf.so 0x4051f240
04-23 14:45:37.911: D/dalvikvm(11675): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.artifex.mupdf/lib/libmupdf.so 0x4051f240, skipping init
04-23 14:45:37.911: E/libmupdf(11675): Opening document...
04-23 14:45:37.941: E/libmupdf(11675): Done!
04-23 14:45:37.961: I/[POST_RESELECT](11675): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40103c78,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:45:37.961: I/[POST_RESELECT](11675): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4013faa8,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:45:37.961: I/[POST_RESELECT](11675): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40103c78,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:45:37.971: I/[POST_RESELECT](11675): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4013faa8,-1,0,-1,0)
04-23 14:45:38.581: E/libmupdf(11675): Goto page 0...
04-23 14:45:38.581: E/libmupdf(11675): PageWidth=1230
04-23 14:45:38.601: E/libmupdf(11675): PageHeight=1514
04-23 14:45:38.601: E/libmupdf(11675): Goto page 1...
04-23 14:45:38.781: D/dalvikvm(11675): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 47% free 2851K/5379K, external 91K/541K, paused 92ms
04-23 14:45:38.881: D/dalvikvm(11675): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 48% free 2850K/5379K, external 583K/1095K, paused 86ms
04-23 14:45:38.991: E/libmupdf(11675): PageWidth=1082
04-23 14:45:38.991: E/libmupdf(11675): PageHeight=1332
04-23 14:45:38.991: E/libmupdf(11675): Goto page 0...
04-23 14:45:38.991: E/libmupdf(11675): PageWidth=1230
04-23 14:45:39.001: E/libmupdf(11675): PageHeight=1514
04-23 14:45:39.001: I/libmupdf(11675): In native method
04-23 14:45:39.001: I/libmupdf(11675): Checking format
04-23 14:45:39.001: I/libmupdf(11675): locking pixels
04-23 14:45:39.001: E/libmupdf(11675): Rendering page=320x393 patch=[0,0,320,393]
04-23 14:45:39.801: E/libmupdf(11675): Rendered
04-23 14:45:39.801: I/libmupdf(11675): In native method
04-23 14:45:39.801: I/libmupdf(11675): Checking format
04-23 14:45:39.801: I/libmupdf(11675): locking pixels
04-23 14:45:39.801: E/libmupdf(11675): Rendering page=320x455 patch=[0,0,320,455]
04-23 14:45:40.201: E/libmupdf(11675): Rendered
04-23 14:45:40.201: E/libmupdf(11675): Goto page 1...
04-23 14:45:40.201: E/libmupdf(11675): PageWidth=1082
04-23 14:45:40.231: E/libmupdf(11675): PageHeight=1332
04-23 14:45:40.231: I/libmupdf(11675): In native method
04-23 14:45:40.231: I/libmupdf(11675): Checking format
04-23 14:45:40.231: I/libmupdf(11675): locking pixels
04-23 14:45:40.231: E/libmupdf(11675): Rendering page=320x393 patch=[0,0,320,393]
```

Comment: had u used any PDFRender Class...??????

Answer (score 0):

did you run it on the Emulator..???
if yes then post the logcat output...
& did you make ur own app using muPdf because only muPdf is not working to render the PDF..

see this apps these are Free..

[Droidreade](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)

[APV](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)

try these

Comment: no @Aze...I haven't run it on emulator. and Yes I have just used Mupdf source and thirdparty libraries, compiled and build my own so file..

Comment: then bro u need to use PDFRender class...
for that this two apps are Free & best...

you can download its source code compile it & run it...

in both of this APV is best..
it has a script folder just run the script all the third parties will automatically copied then u just have to compile & then run the app.....

Comment: bro i tried APV very earlier and it worked for me well enough for huge pdf's and password protected too,  but while i was testing a pdf, which had only 12 pages with a lot of graphics, APV was not able to render it and i was surprised..

Comment: yes thats only problem with it..
& as it is using native libraries its get too much load thats y it crash...
if u want a perfect Pdfreader then use ezPDF but its not free u have to search for it.....

Comment: hey..i tried my code on emulator....but i blv it needs an external directory and hence it is giving me a NullPointerException..

Comment: i just checked and got to 9 dat i was getting NullPointerexception coz, i wasn't having any pdf file...but nw i do have it, and my new error is: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mupdf: findLibrary returned null

Comment: its not getting he file to render the library or file which can help muPDF to read PDf..

Comment: No luck getting the solution to this problem yet:-(

Comment: Yeah.just need to render the pdf, no manipulations or modifications to the Pdf.

Comment: then use APV 
its working fine with my app...
even my app has annotation although it works very good...

Comment: hey dude..i got something about my issue ie. my real question.. I was able to install the app and it tries to render the pdf but not able to render actually..if i had my package name as: "com.artifex.mupdf", it would hv work, but since i had some different package name, it was not able to render. I don't 9 what cud be done!!!!

Comment: First u see the package name of the mupdf.c file that file must call the native library..
as in apv the package name is same in PDFRender.c file & in PDF.java file that both must to be the same.....
check & let me knw..
or if possible show me ur code...

is it saying some file or library missing exception or error...